# How to fix: Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target

Tags: xcode

I tried using the simulator and real phone, I still get the same error.

ERROR: **Thread 1: Exception: Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target**

Here's the complete ViewController. Please see the codes below.

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class CellClass: UITableViewCell {
    
}

class ContactUsViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var messageField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var subjectField: UIButton!
    
    let transparentView = UIView()
    let tableView = UITableView()
    
    var selectedButton = UIButton()
    
    var dataSource = [String]()
    
    var MFMailComposeResultCancelled = MFMailComposeResult(rawValue: 0)
    var MFMailComposeResultFailed = MFMailComposeResult(rawValue: 0)
    var MFMailComposeResultSaved = MFMailComposeResult(rawValue: 0)
    var MFMailComposeResultSent = MFMailComposeResult(rawValue: 0)
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(CellClass.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    }
    
    func addTransparentView(frames: CGRect) {
        let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first
        transparentView.frame = window?.frame ?? self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(transparentView)
        
        tableView.frame = CGRect(x: frames.origin.x, y: frames.origin.y + frames.height, width: frames.width, height: 0)
        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
               
        transparentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.9)
        tableView.reloadData()
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(removeTransparentView))
        transparentView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        transparentView.alpha = 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {self.transparentView.alpha = 0.5
            self.tableView.frame = CGRect(x: frames.origin.x, y: frames.origin.y + frames.height + 5, width: frames.width, height: CGFloat(self.dataSource.count * 50))
        }, completion: nil)
    }
    
    @IBAction func subjectList(_ sender: Any) {
        dataSource = [" General Inquiries", " Purchase STL File"," Purchase an Eternity Band Ring", " Inquire about Measurements"]
        selectedButton = subjectField
        addTransparentView(frames: subjectField.frame)
    }
    
    @objc func removeTransparentView() {
        let frames = selectedButton.frame
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: { self.transparentView.alpha = 0
            self.tableView.frame = CGRect(x: frames.origin.x, y: frames.origin.y + frames.height, width: frames.width, height: 0)
        }, completion: nil)
    }
    
    @IBAction func sendTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let toCS = ["info@ezbandcalculator.com"]
        let mc: MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mc.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mc.setToRecipients(toCS)
        mc.setSubject(selectedButton.currentTitle!)
        mc.setMessageBody("Message: \(String(describing: messageField?.text))", isHTML: false)
        self.present(mc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
           switch result.rawValue {
           case MFMailComposeResultCancelled!.rawValue:
               print ("Cancelled")
           case MFMailComposeResultFailed!.rawValue:
               print ("Failed")
           case MFMailComposeResultSaved!.rawValue:
               print ("Saved")
           case MFMailComposeResultSent!.rawValue:
               print ("Sent")
           default:
               break
           }
           
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    @IBAction func dismissKeyboard(_ sender: Any) {
        self.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}

extension ContactUsViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = dataSource[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedButton.setTitle(dataSource[indexPath.row], for: .normal)
        removeTransparentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check whether your current device can send mail or not before presenting.

```
if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
    // present
}
```

Refer: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller/1616879-cansendmail